# Using variable inside regex method, can't get it to work

Tags: javascript, regex

I have read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/494046/4275509) and I understand how to use the Regex constructor and have this this method numerous times before, but in this example I can't understand why the test() method does not return true. Please help! :-)

```js
// This returns true
console.log(/HYD\./gi.test("HYD.,CYLINDER"))

// Now I will use a variable inside this test method so
// I have to use the Regex constructor

const abbreviation = "HYD.";

// I have to replace all "." with "\." to be compliant with the regex language.
const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${abbreviation.replace(".", "\\.")}\\b`, "gi");
console.log(regex)

// Now testing the regex constructor
console.log(regex.test("HYD.,CYLINDER"));
```

Comment: The problem is the second `\b` which doesn't match between the dot and the comma.

Answer (score 1):

Your two regexes aren't the same. The one you're constructing, with `\b` "Word Boundary" markers, are causing your regex to fail.

This is because `.,` is not a word boundary.

Try with a literal `/\bHYD\.\b/gi` and you'll see it doesn't match either.

Comment: Ah, sorry! To tired. Thank you!